# Create blockchain wallet via api

Tags: blockchain, wallet

i'm trying to execute my first blockchain api via the postman extension under chrome apps

so after installing all required ENV and the node js server to run the blockchain

when test this api link ( as POST method)

http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create
and passed data

```
{
    password : "MY_PASSWORD", 
    api_code : "cc1710f4-a89c-405b-99c5-*******"
}
```

The the result is always the same ::

```
{
    "error": "Missing query parameter: password"
}
```

So please how to bypass this annoying problem

Comment: can you provide the ref.link for required ENV setup ?

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of POST** method use **GET** method as given in blockchain.info API.
try following URL.I got response by using get method

http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create?password=Enterpassword$&api_code=cc1710f4-a89c-405b-99c5-*******